# MDE FIle - How to view code

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a set of reports in Microsoft Access that use a single oracle database, now it uses an MDE file to display these reports via a form . How can I view the code that is used to generate these reports ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't. All `.mde` files have the source code stripped out of them precisely so that it cannot be altered or extracted.

Longer answer: You can't directly retrieve the source code from an `.mde` file because it's not in there. There *may* be an application out there that could *decompile* `.mde` code, but I don't know of anyone who has used such a thing.

Comment: @JamesKhan The compiled code is still in there (in binary form), and that's what Access uses to generate the reports.